# Change android:layout_marginTop dynamically

Tags: android, xml, layout, dynamic

How do I change this attribute of .xml file dynamically?:

```
     android:layout_marginTop="60dp"
```

I use RelativeLayout

Answer (score 1):

you can set layout params on your view and set margins on your params http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/ViewGroup.LayoutParams.html

for example, this is how you can do it for a LinearLayout

```
LinearLayout.LayoutParams layoutParams = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(
     LinearLayout.LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT, LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);

layoutParams.setMargins(left, top, right, bottom);
```

and then just `setLayoutParams`

For a RelativeLayout you can just change LinearLayout with RelativeLayout :)